# is $y=f(x)$ and $x$ is undefined at $x=n$ the same as writing $y=f(x)\cdot \dfrac{x-n}{x-n}$

Tags: functions

This does appear to make sense to me, because in the second one $y$ is  undefined at $x=n$, so I think It should be true. I posted this question to make sure that that I was correct and That I would be able to use this on all functions.

note: $n$ is a constant

Comment: While this does work, many people will interpret $(x-n)/(x-n)$ to be $1$ even though it is technically undefined when $x=n$.  If you wish to explicitly make a function undefined when $x=n$, it is probably better to explicitly say that you are undefined at that point.

Answer (score 0):

surely if $f(x)$ is already undefined at $x=n$ then it should be something like:
$$f(x)=\frac{g(x)}{x-n}$$
where $g$ is continuous

Comment: What about $f(x)=1/x^2$ then?